# You just happened to have it on you

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "You just happened to have it on you" mean in the following conversation?

> R: There are some things in my research log which might be relevant to
> your case. Now that you have stopped blustering, I'll read you some
> things before my patient returns.
>
> B: You just happened to have it on
> you.

Comment: wouldn't this be better on an ESL site ?

Comment: You've chosen the wrong answer! In this particular instance, @Aparente's answer is correct. The speaker is being cynical or sarcastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> R: There are some things in my research log which might be relevant to your case. Now that you have stopped blustering, I'll read you some things before my patient returns.
>
> B: You just happened to have it on you.

B is being sarcastic, and making fun of R.  It isn't typical to carry around one's research log.  B is thinking, "Isn't it weird that just when this disagreement occurs, R can conveniently whip out his research log to back up his point of view?"

Answer (score 1):

It means B thinks this is a coincidence (or unlikely or unplanned) that R has the diary with him at that moment.

Another example:

A: can you give me back my sunglasses next time I see you?
B: I happen to have them here right now! I can give them back to you now.

Here, B didn't plan to return A's sunglasses at that moment (the sunglasses could have easily been at home instead) but B "happened to have them" with him (ie he wasn't planning on returning the glasses, he just had them with him coincidentally).